# Where can if find #define in Objective-C project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am working with an iOS project that uses

```
#if defined (FREE_VERSION)
```

The project has two targets, each of a free and paid version. If I run the free, the code under the above statement fires, and if I run the paid, the "else" code fires. That's all as expected.

But when I search the project for "FREE_VERSION" or "#defined", I get no results (other than the "#if defined" statements). So where might FREE_VERSION be defined?

I'm not very familiar with pre-processor directives and #define, so I may not be using the right terminology here. But, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The more readable version for #if defined(FREE_VERSION) is #ifdef FREE_VERSION

Comment: @Szu Whether it's clearer or not is a matter of opinion. For example, I definitely prefer the more expressive `if defined(...)`.

Comment: In Xcode, "Jump to definition". Only problem is when FREE_VERSION is not defined, because then there is no definition.

Comment: Definitions that go into all the classes are usually bundled up in pch (pre compiled header) files. That is the logical place to put this in. or individually in the header files of the classes that use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With defines like this, I assume you will find it in `project settings` -> `build settings` -> `preprocessing`.

The idea behind it is that you have several schemes/build targets which behave differently and you don't have to change code to setup your build, you just switch between schemes/targets.

`DEBUG` is an example of a similar macro, which is defined by default for `Debug` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you to #define it somewhere. You could have a constants header file and define it there.

In free version:

Global.h:

```
    #define FREE_VERSION
```

Then you can comment it out later when compiling paid version.

Comment: That makes sense, but it is apparently already defined somewhere. And I don't ever comment it out (I can't since I cannot find it), but everything runs as expected when I run the free or paid version. It is somehow defined for the free target, but not for the paid.